# Convergence of average of i.i.d. Bernoulli to Normal will be slower for p closer to 0 or 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

this is true. If you fit a normal to the data you see, if you have small samples, the normal is spread out in shape. So the area cut out by the $x=0$ line or $x=1$ line is larger than the case when $p=0.5$. Any other intuitive explanation to back this claim? How do people go about proving this statement? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the average of Bernoulli random variables?

Comment: @Xiaomi yes, thanks for pointing out

Comment: I'm assuming you don't mean the average, but the right renormalization to get the central limit theorem to apply? (Otherwise, it converges to $p$ a.s. (LLN), not to normal (CLT))

Comment: @ClementC. good point. $\sqrt{n}(\bar X-p)$, I think

Comment: What do you mean by *"the area cut out by the $x=0$ line or $x=1$ line"*?

Comment: @r.e.s. If you generate many $\bar{X}$, and plot it's histogram it will resemble a Normal with variance proportional to the reciprocal of the number of samples $n$ used in $\bar{X}$. So I am imagining my self fitting a Normal distribution with specific variance to it. When $n$ is small, Vast chunks of the fitted normal will lie outside either $x=0$, or $x=1$. Sorry for the wordy explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A Bernoulli$(p)$ distribution has $\mu=p$ , $\sigma^2=p(1-p)$

By the CLT , the CDF of the variable $Z=\sum (X_i-p)/\sqrt{n p (1-p)}$ will tend to a standard normal distribution $\Phi(z)$.

The [Berry–Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) gives a bound:

$$ F_Z(z)-\Phi(z)\le \frac{C\rho}{\sigma^3} \sqrt{n}$$

where $C\approx 0.4$ and $\rho=E(|(X-\mu)^3|)$. In our case $\rho=\left( 1-p\right) \,{{p}^{3}}+{{\left( 1-p\right) }^{3}}p$

The factor $\rho/\sigma^3$ has a mininum for $p=1/2$, and grows without bound at the extremes. Hence, it's to be expected (though this is not a proof) that the convergence is slower when $p\to 0$ or $p\to 1$.

[image]

You could also revisit several [proofs of convergence](http://www.m-hikari.com/imf/imf-2017/9-12-2017/p/baguiIMF9-12-2017.pdf) and examine the limiting arguments when $p\to 0$. For example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2579435/312) reveals that negligible terms at the limit ($n \to \infty$) actually depend on $\sqrt{npq}$ going to infinite. Hence, if some $n_1$ is "big enough" for, say $p=0.01$, then for $p=0.001$ we'll need  a new $n$ ten times bigger.

Comment: But the *upper* bound given by Berry—Esséen is only a *hint*: to prove what the OP's mean, one would want also a *lower* bound...

Comment: Exactly, that's why I said that this is not a proof